# Fail maven build based on script

Tags: maven

I was wondering if there was a way to fail a maven build based on the return of a script. I did not find any useful resources on the web.

Use case:

We have a lot of configurations files. I want to check the files for the required properties, if they all have them -> continue build, if they don't -> fail build. Is this possible with a simple bash script?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of script? What does it look like? Can you give a bit more info? What exactly is the usecase you're trying to solve as well?

Comment: We have a lot of configurations files. I want to check the files for the required properties, if they all have them -> continue build, if they don't -> fail build. Is this possible with a simple bash script?

Comment: Sounds like you could use the Enforcer Plugin instead http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireProperty.html

Comment: Thank you so much, I also found the maven exec plugin. I am going to compare both of them.

Comment: Or simply write some unit tests for that..

Answer (score 1):

Is that a Maven project? Then check the property files with unit tests.

I'm using unit tests for all kinds of "convention" tests; that's those things where everyone "assumes" that "something is so."

I usually check:

- Are all mandatory config options defined?
- Does the code access config options which don't exist?
- When production bugs come in, where clients make config mistakes, I add tests to make sure they get a good error message in the future

How do I check access to config options? I put each config option name into a constant and then use reflection to collect them all. I do the same with all the options in property files and then compare the two lists.